# Swapping two values in C

Tags: c

I have written this program to make the value of a in b and the value of b in a.

For this I created temp as a temporary variable and this is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int changevalue(int a, int b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b; 
    b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    a = 10;
    b = 20; 
    printf("the value of a is %d \n and b is %d",a,b);
    changevalue(a,b);
    printf("the value of a is %d \n and b is %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

But the values of a and b did not change .

Where is the problem?

Comment: changevalue change the values of its parameters (copied from main's a and b) but returns nothing, and main's variables are untouched.

Comment: You have to use pointers.

Comment: Read call by value and call by reference to learn more.

Comment: In C language, when you declare a function with `int function(int a, int b)` and invoke it, the values of `a` and `b` inside the function are copies, thus the original values (in `main`) won't change

Comment: @GuidoFlohr I have started programming since a week ! looking for pointers on google gives too much information that i can not start studying successfly, can you suggest a good reference to learn with with basic and simple examples ?

Comment: Pointers are described in every book or course for C. Just follow your current course, and they will come, when it's time.

Comment: You can also replace your *function* `changevalue` with a *macro*: `#define changevalue(x, y) { x += y; y = x - y; x -= y; }`. The difference is that a macro is like a template. The code `changevalue(a,b)` is expanded by the preprocessor into `{ a += b; b = a - b; a -= b; }`. In fact, that is a simpler and faster solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changevalue(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a   = *b; 
    *b   = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int b=20;
    printf("the value of a is %d \n and b is %d",a,b);
    changevalue(&a,&b);
    printf("the value of a is %d \n and b is %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```